# Module for ES6 features

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6

Is there a JavaScript module, that can be installed in current versions of Node, that provides some ES6 features e.g. Map? (The version of Map provided by `node --harmony` doesn't yet implement enough features to be useful.)

Comment: Is npmjs.org down for you? https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=es6 `->` https://www.npmjs.org/package/es6-collections

Comment: @FelixKling Doesn't seem to work, e.g. when I import es6-collections, then `m = new Map()` followed by `m.keys()` it gives an error message, same as when I tried using the version provided by `node --harmony`, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ah, checking the source, seems like mostly not implemented, and node probably use the same code. No worries, I'll just write my own.

Comment: There are a number of projects. https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/ is one of the more popular, and there is of course Traceur if you want any of the language features. es6-shim should have Map.keys()

Answer (score 0):

This [compatibility matrix](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) should be of use.

Of particular interest, might be google's [traceur compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) which will translate es6 code to es5 to run anywhere

Comment: How exactly does this help to find a module?